# How can I find the Feature Activation Dependency Powershell

Tags: powershell, feature-activation, solution-deployment

I am running a recursive function that activates many features in powershell however I need to find the child feature a feature is dependent on before it is activated. How can I do this in powershell.

Assume all the solutions have been correctly deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [ActivationDependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.activationdependencies.aspx) of the [SPFeatureDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.aspx) object.  In SP2010, you would do something like this :

```
Get-SPFeature | % {
    $feature = $_
    $featureName = $_.DisplayName
    $feature.ActivationDependencies | % {
        $dep = Get-SPFeature $_.FeatureId
        $depName = $dep.DisplayName

        write-output "$featureName,$depName"
    }
}
```

If you need to do this for SP2007, then [This blog post](http://darrinbishop.com/blog/2008/07/getfeaturedefinition) has a good example of how to go about it.

Comment: A more "PowerShell"'is answer could be `Get-SPFeature | Select -ExpandProperty ActivationDependencies`

Comment: Thanks Dave that looks like exactly what I am looking for thanks.

Comment: @AndersRask that shows the dependency IDs but not the features themselves.  However, it is a great start for finding the dependency of a single known feature, I slightly modified it to this: `get-spfeature PublishingSite | select -expandproperty ActivationDependencies | % { Get-SPFeature $_.FeatureId }`